# NetworkOnMainThread using AsyncSubject RxJava in Android

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I’m facing a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` on a `AsyncSubject` **even when I apply the schedulers in the returning `Observable`**.
Why we need to apply the `Schedulers` on the `Subject`?

I missed this explanation in the javadocs of `Subjects`, why the `Subject` goes in the main thread if we don’t compose it? Can someone point a documentation explaining this?

There’s a sample of the code below to illustrate the scenario.

This is the use case:

```
/*** Makes a network call to retrieve a search result, it returns an Observable<SearchResult> */
private Observable<SearchResult> call(String searchQuery){
    return mSearchWebService.call(searchQuery);
}

/* Same code but with a  a NetworkOnMainThreadException */
private Observable<SearchResult> call(String searchQuery){
    final Subject<SearchResult, SearchResult> subject = AsyncSubject.create();
    mSearchWebService.call(“let me google something”)
            .subscribe(subject::onNext, subject::onError, subject::onCompleted);
    // When we apply the schedulers in the subject, it works fine, but why it doesn’t apply the schedulers of the observables?
    // This works: mSearchWebService.call(“let me google something”)
    // .compose(mBackgroundThreadTransformer.applySchedulers())
    // .subscribe(subject::onNext, subject::onError, subject::onCompleted);
    return subject;
}
```

This is the code in the presenter:

```
private void onSearchButtonClicked(){
    searchUseCase.call(“let me google something”).compose(mBackgroundThreadTransformer.applySchedulers())
        .subscribe(searchResult -> show(searchResult),
            e -> Timber.d(e, "Failed to search”)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyse the behavior.

From the first method that does not return the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` you apply the schedulers to the `Observable` returned by `mSearchWebService.call(searchQuery)`. That is clear.

Whaat about the second case? You create `Subject` the return it and apply the schedulers to what is returned from the function. `Subject` is returned and it gets the schedulers. `mSearchWebService.call(“let me google something”)` is not scheduled by `mBackgroundThreadTransformer`

What is `Subject` from the point of view of `mSearchWebService.call(...)`? It is the `Subscriber`. So `mSearchWebService.call(...) ends (without assigning any particular`Scheduler`) passing the result to`Subject`(which runs on`mBackgroundThreadTransformer`) which passes the result to the end`Subscriber`.

Solution:
apply the `Scheduler`'s to `mSearchWebService.call(...)` explicitly.